# Which visa route is appropriate?

Tags: visas, uk, study

I am a university teacher in Algeria and I am conducting my Ph.D reasearch in Algeria. I was granted an 18-month-funded research leave to finalize my thesis at SOAS, London. My question is which type of visa do  I have apply for ? 
What vexes me is the Academic Visa's maximum duration is 12 month , and it is not extendable.
Plz urgent.

Comment: Did you ask the school what they recommended?

Comment: This belongs on [Expatriates.SE].

Comment: Are you registered at SOAS or at an Algerian university?

Answer (score 1):

The [UK Tier 4 (General) student visa](https://www.gov.uk/tier-4-general-visa) would be the category.

> [SOAS Tier 4 Students](https://www.soas.ac.uk/students/international/tier-4-visas/)
>
> Everything you need to know about getting a Tier 4 Student Visa, including applying for a Confirmation of Acceptance (CAS).
>
> [Tier 4 Doctoral School Postgraduate research students](https://www.soas.ac.uk/doctoralschool/tier-4-students/)

Comment: Thanks indeed. As I understand TIer 4 is a student visa. I am not to get an SOAS degree; I am just conducting my research to finalize my Algerian degree.